# Compiler time in ipython3

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jit, timeit

Executed the command,

```
timeit a = (3**(10**7))%24;
```

on ipython3 and got the output,

```
100000000 loops, best of 3: 13.5 ns per loop
Compiler time: 3.39 s
```

Does compiler time mean the time taken by the JIT compiler in ipython3 ?

Using ipython3 v1.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython does not implement any kind of JIT compiler. 'Compiler time' represents the time for Python to compile your textual code to Python bytecode.

I was surprised by your timing - it's a very simple expression, and should take almost no time to compile. IPython doesn't report the compiler time if it's less than 0.1 seconds, and I've never seen it show up before. So I went and tried it myself, and sure enough...

```
In [2]: timeit a = (3**(10**7))%24;
10000000 loops, best of 3: 20.7 ns per loop
Compiler time: 5.54 s
```

So what's going on?

The answer is CPython's peephole optimiser, and specifically the function `fold_binops_on_constants()`, found [here (C code)](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/66f033096ddc/Python/peephole.c#l148). `10**7` is a binary operation on two constants, which is guaranteed to always have the same value. So Python helpfully precomputes that value, and replaces `10**7` in your program with the constant `10000000`. But now `3**10000000` is a binary operation on two constants, so it computes that as well. And finally it does the same to the last part of the operation, so the bytecode looks like this:

```
In [11]: dis.dis("a = (3**(10**7))%24")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               7 (9)
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

All it's actually doing when your code runs is to store the constant 9 in the name `a`!

This would be helpful in actual code - that expression is precomputed when the `.pyc` files are created, so you save several seconds each time your program is run. It's not so helpful for timing, because your actual computation is only run once by the compiler. To force it to do the timing, we can simply make something from the innermost part of the expression a variable, so Python won't optimise it (the peephole optimiser is very basic, nothing like modern C compilers or JIT compilers):

```
In [5]: b = 7

In [6]: timeit a = (3**(10**b))%24;
1 loops, best of 3: 5.5 s per loop
```

Comment: Thank You @Thomas K. Where did you learn about the peephole optimiser ? And what is your system's configuration ?

Comment: I can't remember where I learned about it - it looks like there are one or two blog posts about it if you want to learn more. My system is running Debian, though I don't think that's relevant to Python bytecode compilation.